# How to launch coroutine in Editor with the "Editor coroutine" package?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to build a tool in the Unity Editor with an EditorWindow on his own. This tool will need to access a MySQL DB through PHP files so I need to use coroutines. I looked for a solution and fall upon a preview package "Editor Coroutine" and installed it. I don't see how it works and the documentation doesn't say anything (or anything i've understanded) about how to use it. Do you know any way to make this thing work properly ?

I've tried to simply do a "StartCoroutine()", to call it from an Editor class or to create an object (GameObject) to call it, but none of this work :/.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. I ended up with the following code, which executes the webrequest in a non-coroutine method.

```
private void UpdateVersion(string message)
{
    string post_url = NetworkManager.baseUrl + "VersionUpdate.php";
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Message", message); 
    form.AddField("Version", Application.version);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(post_url, form);
    www.chunkedTransfer = false;
    www.SendWebRequest();

    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        // do nothing
    }   

    if(www.error == null){
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("error!: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the accepted answer's `while` loop completely blocks the Editor until the download is done. For a simple text that might be fine but for larger files this might become an issue.

There is however [`EditorApplication.update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-update.html) you can subscripe to in order to call a method every frame in the Editor. So for an EditorWindow you could do something like

```
private IEnumerator currentDownload;

private void ProcessDownload()
{
    if(currentDownload!=null) currentDownload.MoveNext();
}

private IEnumerator UpdateVersion(string message)
{
    string post_url = NetworkManager.baseUrl + "VersionUpdate.php";
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Message", message); 
    form.AddField("Version", Application.version);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(post_url, form);
    www.chunkedTransfer = false;
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.error == null){
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("error!: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
// makes sure the callback is added only once
EditorApplication.update -= ProcessDownload;
EditorApplication.update += ProcessDownload;

currentDownload = UpdateVersion("whatever string");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into this a bit later though, I'm in a project with a limited time and even if the accepted answer isn't perfect, it works and I need to move on :/